# Using Servlet data (HttpServletRequest) in another method

Tags: java, servlets, ip, remote-desktop

Im using:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    System.out.println("IP " + Ip);
    processRequest(request, response);
}

public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    out.println("<h3>You have entered name : "+name+"<br>");
    out.println("<b><font color='blue'>IP Address of request : </font></b>" + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</h3>");
    System.out.println("<h3>You have entered name : " + name + "<br>");
    System.out.println("<b><font color='blue'>IP Address of request : </font></b>" + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</h3>");
}
```

..which return the users IP address and I need to store it as a variable and use the variable in:

```
public void setRc(String rc) throws IOException { //need to start/call doGet() and/or processRequest() here....
    try {
        Process d = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\commands\\psexec \\\\" + Ip + " -i -s -d \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Configuration Manager Console\\AdminUI\\bin\\i386\\rc.exe\" 1 " + rc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("FROM CATCH " + e.toString());
        this.rc = rc;
    }
}
```

This is for a web application for our IT group - to open a remote connecting gui on the users side - and it will have the target pc as the variable following rc.

Therefore, the command will be: psexec - on web app users desktop, with parameters xyz and running rc.exe on target pc...

The way it works: user enters information (into web app) pertaining to 1.)user, 2.)pc or 3.) ID# - then they click the submit button...
then... Information is returned to screen (from SQL) 
then... the Computer name is placed into command lines (as rc - in the .java page) and the web app shows remote command possibilities - as a button.... 
e.g "click button to perform abc.exe on pc name xxx-xxxxxx

So, I need to incorporate the IP address of the IT group user - into the command line...

note: running a command on the target is simple bc - the server opens a cmd and performs psexec to perform .exe on target
However, in this example the server needs to run cmd on the user - that opens the gui on the users pc - with the target pc set as the parameter in rc.exe...

so...example one goes: user -> server -> target
and..example two goes: user -> server -> user -> target

Thank you.

Here is the button - that starts setRun:

```
<td>
    <form name="rc" action="index.jsp" />
    Remote Control:<input type="submit" value="${UserDetails.Computer_Name}" onsubmit=jsp:setProperty name="rc"/>
</form>               
</td>
```

Comment: Do you need to pass the ip from one method to other? I think I don't undertand really your question.

Comment: yes. setRun needs call doGet and then doGet needs to pass Ip to setRun so Ip can be used within setRun

Comment: Can't you modify the parameters for setRc()? Is in another class?